# Git repository created without a master branch

Tags: git, repository, git-branch

I want to create a new shared git repository for a new project (on a VM).

I ran `git --bare init` from `/.../git/new_proj.git`, but a master branch is not created in the `.../git/new_proj.git/refs/heads` directory.
I also ran `sudo chmod 777 -R` on my directory, but it didn't help, and still no master is created after the `init` command.

**Edit:**
I even tried to use `git init` (without the bare flag), but still the master branch was not created.

Google wasn't much help in this matter...

Anyone know what the problem is? Something I'm missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's already in the comments on the [other answer so far](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21252989/1256452), but this is perfectly normal: a new repository, "bare" or not, has no commits, so it has no references either.

It does have a `HEAD`, which is a file named `HEAD` in the repository (the `.git` directory), containing a symbolic branch name reference.  If you `cat HEAD` you'll see `ref: refs/heads/master`, meaning that the new repository is "on branch master", *even though branch master does not yet exist*.  Again, this is a perfectly normal state of affairs.  You're said to be "on an unborn branch", at this point.

When you add one or more commits to this empty repository, the `master` branch can—if it's a bare repo, you may be adding this via `git push` which may not provide a `master` branch, so let's not say "does" :-) although usually `master` does—come into existence at that point, with the reference pointing to the new commit (or the new tip commit of a chain of commits).

In any repo (bare or not, again), you can be "on" a branch that does not exist.  In particular, in an ordinary repo, you can do:

```
$ git checkout --orphan newbranch
```

which puts you "on" `newbranch` (by writing `ref: refs/heads/newbranch` into `HEAD`) without actually *creating* `newbranch` yet, making `newbranch` an "unborn branch".  The next commit then causes `newbranch` to come into existence, and that commit has no parent commits (hence the `--orphan` part): it is a new root commit.  This is the same way `master` comes into existence on *its* first commit.

If you like, you can look at it in terms of underlying mechanism: when git creates a new commit, the steps used to update `HEAD` go like this:<sup>1</sup>

1. Read contents of `HEAD` file.
2. Is it a symbolic ref such as `ref: refs/heads/master`? if yes, go to step 4.
3. No ("detached HEAD" case): create commit with parent given by commit ID in `HEAD` and write new SHA-1 into `HEAD`.  Stop, we are done.
4. Read SHA-1 of referred-to branch (e.g., `.git/refs/heads/master`, or from packed refs).
5. If no SHA-1 is available because branch does not exist yet, create root commit, else create commit whose parent is the given SHA-1.  Write new SHA-1 to referred-to branch.  Stop, we are done.

As an interesting side note, when refs get packed, "active" ones (like whichever branch you're developing on, let's say `devel` for instance) wind up in `.git/packed-refs`, but are quickly updated with new values.  Those new values go *only* in the `.git/refs/heads/devel` file: the `.git/packed-refs` file retains a `refs/heads/devel` entry, but it's stale (and hence ignored).  (You're not supposed to depend on this: external programs, such as shell scripts, should use `git branch` or `git update-ref` or `git symbolic-ref` as appropriate, to read and write ref-names and SHA-1 values.  Occasionally, though, it's useful to be able to go in and edit refs directly.  Think of it as a modern-day equivalent of a hex editor for disk sectors. :-) )

---

<sup>1</sup>This all assumes you are not creating a merge commit.  If you *are* in the middle of a merge, another file in the repository (`.git/MERGE_HEAD`) supplies the extra merge parent IDs.

Answer (score 6):

i have same issue and fixed 
- first of all use git add command after that use commit command finally use git branch to show your branched
my git version 1.9

```
git add -A
git commit -m "initialize"
git branch
```

Answer (score 2):

Bare git repos (repos created by issuing `git init --bare`) will not have a working tree attached to them.
What you can do is go to the `repo /.../git/new_proj.git` and add the bare repo you created as a remote: `git remote add bare_origin <link to bare repo>` and then try pushing your commits to this `bare_origin` repo form there.

Also, do you have any particular reason in creating a bare repository instead of a normal one?

Comment: The repository I'm trying to created is a shared one, so that's why I'm using --bare. But even when I tried the git init without the bare flag, no master was created. Also I don't understand your suggestion - what's bare_origin? (Please bear in mind that I'm new to git. :))

Comment: When you make a first commit in the repo, it will automatically create a new branch called master. So, what you can do is start working in this directory as you wish and when you are ready to make your first commit, do so. Then, issue a git branch and you should be able to see a master branch. When you do a git init you are just making it a git repo, nothing more.
bare_origin is just some alias to the remote branch, nothing more. You could name it anything and you can refer the remote branch by its name.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help! How about upvoting it and/or accepting it as the answer? :-)

Comment: @Ayelet, a minor nitpick: gravetti is *almost* correct describing the state of a newborn repo: the `HEAD` ref in this repo in fact *does* point to a branch named "master" but this branch does not really exist: try to do `cat .git/HEAD` followed by `ls .git/refs/heads` in a freshly created repository. So the branch "master" is ready to exist but does not actually does. Note that while in this state, you can do, say, `git checkout -b test` -- `HEAD` will be retargetted at `refs/heads/test` but no branch named "test" will actually be created.

Comment: @Ayelet, In other words, a branch cames to existence when it can point to a real commit.  No commits -- no branch.  That's the essense of Git branches: they are mere pointers.

Comment: @kostix yes, you are right. Thanks for pointing it out. I believe the master branch gets created when a git init is issued. You just have to make a commit to see it! Also, a git status on a freshly created repo would show the 'On branch master'.

Comment: @gravetii, yeah, because that's what is read from the `HEAD` ref which is a symbolic reference pointing to that unborn branch.