# Create a new Xamarin project with GIT

Tags: git, version-control, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I created a new Xamarin.iOS project and used GIT for version control. You start with a master branch. Now I wanted to start with the project on the develop branch. Therefore I tried to locally create a new develop branch in Xamarin Studio. If I click OK nothing happens. No develop branch is created.

`git status` gives the following:

```
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .gitignore
    MobileTPS.sln
    MobileTPS/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Why doesn't set the template everything correctly up? It seems that I've to add all files by myself.

Now I wanted to display the current branches with `git show-branch -a` and I get

> No revs to be shown.

So what are the appropriate steps to start working on my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the missing files with `git add xxx`.
2. Make a commit (initial commit to [create the master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21255920/426227)).
3. Now you can create a develop branch and switch to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GUI tools available for managing git repository. I personally use SourceTree. There are many other similar tools available online.

*couldn't add a comment due to low reputation score.