# Brand new git repository, no local master

Tags: git

I created a brand new empty git repository/server on my local synology nas server.  Git is installed on my laptop and my desktop and I cloned the repository to both.  I just created something new on my laptop and it's committed to a branch.  The issue is that there's no master branch listed on my laptop.  When I attempt a push I get:

error: src refspec master does not match any

git branch only shows the branch I created and git show-ref only shows that too.

What step did I miss?

Comment: We need to know what steps you took. How did you make the new repository? How are you pushing? Your actual commands would be most useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git repository created without a master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252876/git-repository-created-without-a-master-branch)

Comment: run 'git status' copy and paste the results of running that into the question.

Comment: You probably ran `git init` and then immediately checked out a local issue branch without first creating an "initial" commit. This would have circumvented the creation of the master branch.

Answer (score 1):

```
error: src refspec master does not match any
```

This indicates that you do not have a local branch called master. `src` being "source", your local repository. I guess you made a branch other than master.

`git push origin master` does not mean to push the current branch to origin's master. It says to push from your local master to origin's master. You don't have a local master branch.

How did this happen? If we clone an empty repository it might appear like we have a master branch...

```
$ git init --bare upstream
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/schwern/tmp/upstream/

$ git clone upstream test.git
Cloning into 'test.git'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.

$ cd test.git
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

But we don't.

```
$ git show-ref

$ git branch -v

$ git push origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to '/Users/schwern/tmp/upstream'
```

We have to make a commit to master for it to come into existence.

If you immediately checked out a new branch, master will not exist.

[See this answer for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21255920/14660).

---

If you want to push the current branch to origin, use `git push origin`. If you want to push the current branch to origin's master, use the full syntax: `git push origin +your-branch:master`.

Comment: The "git push origin your-branch:master" did the trick.  Thanks!